Next.js Project 14 Deployed IIS Routing to localhost:3000 Instead of Target IP when
Issue: My project works perfectly locally, but when I deploy it to IIS on my virtual machine (VM), I encounter an issue with Response.redirect(new URL("/", request.nextUrl));.
Flow: I have two API routes—one for a GET request to obtain a token and another for a POST request to redirect to my website. In this scenario, a user sends a payload including token that I store in cookies and then redirect to my base page ('/').
`    export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        let formDataObject: { [key: string]: any } = {};

        formData.forEach((value, key) => {
            formDataObject[key] = value;
        });

        await setSession(JSON.stringify(formDataObject)); //Sets cookies named session
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("xyz: ", error);
        }

        return Response.redirect(new URL("/", request.nextUrl));
    }`

While deploying I followed the following instructions:
Medium
"Now my website is accessible on my server's IP and port (e.g., 12.96.0.47:3000). However, when I retrieve a token and hit the POST endpoint on this IP, it redirects me to localhost:3000, which is the URL where my code is hosted on the server. Instead, it should route to 12.96.0.47:3000. Why is it not routing to that?
For reference my server.js and web.config:
server.js
`    const { createServer } = require('http')
    const { parse } = require('url')
    const next = require('next')

    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    const app = next({ dev })
    const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

    app.prepare().then(() => {
      createServer((req, res) => {
        // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
        // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
        const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
    
        if (pathname === '/a') {
          app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
        } else if (pathname === '/b') {
          app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
        } else {
          handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
        }
      }).listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
      })
    })

web.config:
`    <configuration>
       <appSettings>
        <add key="NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED" value="0" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.webServer>
        <iisnode node_env="production"
          nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
          maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
          maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100"
          namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250"
          maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
          maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
          asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
          initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
          maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
          uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"
          gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
          loggingEnabled="true"
          logDirectory="iisnode"
          debuggingEnabled="true"
          debugHeaderEnabled="false"
          debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
          debuggerPathSegment="debug"
          maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
          maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
          maxLogFiles="20"
          devErrorsEnabled="true"
          flushResponse="false"
          enableXFF="false"
          promoteServerVars=""
          configOverrides="iisnode.yml"
          watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"
          nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;"
          interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;"
        />
        <handlers>
          <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="myapp">
              <match url="/*" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
`

Upon logging a bit I realized in Response.redirect(new URL("/", request.nextUrl)); the request.nextUrl() has the following values:
   NextURL { [Symbol(NextURLInternal)]: { url: URL { href: 'http://localhost:3000/api/xyz/xyz', //this correctly shows the POST endpoint but     with local host origin: 'http://localhost:3000', protocol: 'http:', username: '', password: '', host: 'localhost:3000', hostname: 'localhost', port: '3000', pathname: '/api/xyz/xyz', search: '', searchParams: URLSearchParams {}, hash: '' }, options: { headers: [Object], nextConfig: undefined }, basePath: '', domainLocale: undefined, defaultLocale: undefined, buildId: undefined, locale: undefined, trailingSlash: false } }
Could someone please assist me in understanding why the requests are being directed to localhost instead of the IP address I'm trying to access? Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have installed URL Rewrite and iisnode.
I tried using my server's IP address in
Response.redirect(new URL("12.96.0.47:3000/", request.nextUrl));, but this approach doesn't store cookies on the user's browser.

You mentioned that using the IP address directly doesn't store cookies on the user's browser. This could be due to how cookies are handled in cross-origin requests.
To ensure that cookies are stored properly, you might need to configure your server to allow credentials in cross-origin requests.

@YurongDai My user is calling my API endpoint from another website. On that endpoint, I am setting cookies and then redirecting the user to my main page. Do I still need to consider Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) even though cookies are being set on my API endpoint?

Even though you are setting cookies on your API endpoint and redirecting to your main page, CORS policies still apply. Make sure your server's CORS configuration allows cross-origin requests from the relevant domains and handles CORS-related headers and options correctly to ensure proper functioning of your application across different origins.
